# Avoid looping iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, loops, mobile, subdomain

I have a website that auto-redirects, using JavaScript, to a sub-domain when it detects the site is being viewed in a mobile browser. This sub-domain uses an iframe of the original site to ensure it looks good (long story, not worth getting in to). However, when redirected to the sub-domain, the iframe  loads the entire page and ends up looping the redirect script, never actually loading the page. Is there any way to break out of this iframe loop? I've tried target="_top". Thanks.

Comment: This behavior is evil. Show a small banner at the top to give your users an option, but don't force them.

Comment: The problem is the site looks awful on mobile, something happens to the header which I couldn't figure out. I have a script that auto resizes the iframe to make everything look good. Not elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check whether the page is loaded in an iframe before redirecting:

```
window.location != window.parent.location
```